# Creating a directory that continues to the next number?

Tags: php

I'm Trying to have this button create a directory "item1" and when the button is clicked again, it creates "item2" and so on, for unlimited amount of times.

So far I have this for html (basic):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
   <head>
      <title></title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form id="create_item" action="createfile.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Create Item!" />
      </form>     
   </body>
</html>
```

And my php code:

```
<?php
define("PATH", "/usr/www/tfgwebsite/public/misc/phptest");

$number = 1;
$_POST["dirname"] = "item" . $number;
$test = "set";

if (isset($test)) {
    $dir = $_POST['dirname'];
}

$targetfilename = PATH . '/' . $dir;

if (!is_file($dir) && !is_dir($dir)) {
    mkdir($dir);
    chmod($targetfilename, 0777);
    echo "Created " . $dir . " successfully!";
}
else
{
    echo "File already exists!";
}?>
```

I have tried literally about 80 different combinations of for loops and while statements to try to get $number to increase by 1 if it finds an existing directory, all of them end up creating item1, then infinite looping on me.

Any help would be appreciated, I would post all the things I've tried to show you that I have indeed tried, but they are so hideous, I can't even bear to show such horrible code.

EDIT:

```
<?php
define("PATH", "/usr/www/tfgwebsite/public/misc/phptest");

$items = fopen("items.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$number = fgets($items);
fclose($items);

$_POST["dirname"] = "item" . $number;
$test = "set";

if (isset($test)) {
    $dir = $_POST['dirname'];
}

$targetfilename = PATH . '/' . $dir;

if (!is_file($dir) && !is_dir($dir)) {
    mkdir($dir);
    chmod($targetfilename, 0777);
    echo "Created " . $dir . " successfully!";
    $create = fopen("items.txt", "w+") or die("Unable to open file!");
    fwrite($create, $number + 1);
    fclose($create);
}
else
{
    echo "File already exists!";
}
```

?>

I did this, and it does work. But I do have this awkward .txt in my webserver just counting up, lol.

If there is a better method, please share.

Comment: May be file_exists() should help you.

Comment: store the number in a file or anywhere else, and increase it everytime you create directory

Comment: @kamalpal How would one "store" it? Can't I just store it in a variable somewhere? Somehow? There has to be something I'm missing. I should be able to just increase the variable, no?

Comment: variables lose the values once script is completed, as I understand you need to create a directory on each click, therefore you must store the latest directory number somewhere the value doesn't lost.

Comment: well, your second sol looks logical , but you need to trace it, you need to make sure each step is working as it's supposed to, ex make the `createfile.php` page only try to read file, increase the value , then write it again to the file, and go check the file, if OK, add the next step (creating the folder). and you are done, adding all the code at once when you are not really sure if parts of the code is not doing its job will take you to a maze, remember, **Divide and Conquer** ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look into this code .This is working for me.

-- UPDATED CODE --

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST)) { //print_r($_POST);die;
    define("PATH", $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/create_folder/");

    $files2 = array_diff(scandir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/create_folder/"), array('..', '.', '.svn'));
    $count = count($files2);
    $count_plus = $count + 1;
    if (!is_file(PATH . "item$count_plus") && !is_dir(PATH . "item$count_plus")) {
        mkdir(PATH . "item$count_plus");
        chmod(PATH . "item$count_plus", 0777);
        echo "Created item" . $count_plus . " successfully!";
    } else {

        echo "File already exists!";
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="create_item" action="" method="POST" >
            <input id="submit_button" type="submit" name ="create_folder" value="Create Item!" />
        </form>     
    </body>
</html>
```

This code works like this-

```
It will define PATH constant for location where folders are getting created.

Then it will scan that folder

Then it will check if next folder is present in that directory OR not.

if not then it will create that folder otherwise will give an error.
```

Comment: Downvoting because just giving a huge block of code is not helpful. Explain what OP was doing wrong, or at the very least, explain what you are doing.

Comment: @xbonez you have just downvoted this ans w/o executing ..WOW!!!... please check the code if condition then else condition and then final else condition...First condition is for wheather folder contain any subfolder OR not .We can also avoid second if condition with some changes but downvoting it is a bad idea.

Comment: I'm afraid xbonez might be right. I have no idea what's going on in your code, I am obviously amateur and no explanation is confusing to me.

Comment: @DanDaMan i hv explained please take a look

Comment: @abd: Its not that I doubt your code doesn't work. But, SO is supposed to be more than just a "write my code for me" dump. It's great if you supplement your answer with code, but the main content of your answer needs to explain to the poster what he was doing wrong and how he should correct it.